# Devarim 20: division of roles

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, army-military-war, deuteronomy

Devarim 20:1-9 is a list of instructions that must be given orally to soldiers before setting out to battle. Rashi (on verse 8) explains that a priest says the words in verses 3-4, and that they also say the words in verses 5-7 but quietly so they are repeated by an officer. The words in verse 8 are said by an officer alone. Rashi is basing his comment on Bavli Sotah 43a; in Yerushalmi Sotah 8:9 there’s a dispute over whether or not the officer says anything alone.

My question is about the Bavli/ Rashi interpretation: why would the words in verses 3-7 be originate from a priest, and the words in verse 8 originate from an officer? What is the distinction?

To be clear, I’m not asking how Rashi deduces his interpretation from the text, I get that. I’m asking about the rationale underlying it: why would the Torah divide the roles in that way?